# no such file to load -- silentale-on-rails (new gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I've just completed a new open source gem for the Silentale API and I'm facing a strange issue. In terminal I'm getting an error saying that it can't load the gem however it continues to start the server loading it without any issues.

```
no such file to load -- silentale-on-rails
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:164:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/nick/Projects/dummy_project/config/environment.rb:9
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
no such file to load -- silentale-on-rails
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:169:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/Users/nick/Projects/dummy_project/config/environment.rb:9
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

Could anyone tell me what is going wrong here? The gem can be installed by the following if you want to look at the code and see what might be up;

```
$ sudo gem install silentale-on-rails
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the name of your gem (with hyphens) and the name of the library file (lib/silentale_on_rails).

You can still load it:

```
gem 'silentale-on-rails'      # adds your gems' lib into the load path...
require 'silentale_on_rails'  # ...so this now works.
```

The best solution is of course to have consistent names

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't notice- I did script/generate plugin silentale-on-rails but it still put it as underscores for some reason! Either way, thanks!